Django Inline Formset data not saving
I have created an inline formset which works exactly as I planned on the frontend side-

However I can't seem to access any of the data- it seems like the form isn't saving the data?
Here in the views.py you can see where it should be saving:
class RecipeInline():
    form_class = RecipeForm
    model = Recipe
    template_name = "recipes/recipe_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        named_formsets = self.get_named_formsets()
        if not all((x.is_valid() for x in named_formsets.values())):
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
        
        self.object = form.save()

        for name, formset in named_formsets.items():
            formset_save_func = getattr(self, 'formset_{0}_valid'.format(name), None)
            if formset_save_func is not None:
                formset_save_func(formset)
            else:
                formset.save()
        return redirect('recipes-home')
    
    def formset_variantingredients_valid(self, formset):
        variantingredients = formset.save(commit=False)
        for variantingredient in variantingredients:
            variantingredient.recipe = self.object
            variantingredient.save()

    def formset_images_valid(self, formset):
        images = formset.save(commit=False)
        for image in images:
            image.recipe = self.object
            image.save()

Here is the models.py
    class Image(models.Model):
        recipe = models.ForeignKey(
            Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
            )
        image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.recipe.title
        
    class VariantIngredient(models.Model):
        recipe = models.ForeignKey(
            Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE
            )
        ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
        unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=unit_choice, default='g')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.recipe.title

Here is the forms.py
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title','description','temperature','serving','prep_time', 'cook_time']
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3 create-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-9'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Field('title'),
                Field('description'),
                Field('temperature'),
                Field('serving'),
                Field('prep_time'),
                Field('cook_time'),
            )
        )


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = '__all__'

class VariantIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = VariantIngredient
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'ingredient': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                    }
                ),
            'quantity': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                    }
                ),
            'unit': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                    }
                ),
        }
    

VariantIngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Recipe, VariantIngredient, form=VariantIngredientForm, #Product and Variant are models
    extra=1, can_delete=True
)
ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Recipe, Image, form=ImageForm, #Product and Image are models
    extra=1, can_delete=True
)

In the admin, in my saved form I can only see the standard fields that have saved and not either of these two inline formsets-
Is my issue in the saving of the form itself or am I just not accessing the data correctly?

Please [edit] your question and add a [mre], the code you've shared with us isn't enough for us to reproduce your issue or even just to run it.

I added the extra code for MRE- just didn't want to dump huge amounts of code-

Can you create a repo that can be cloned so that we can test this in your exact environment setup?

Are you writing the database relationship rigth? with M2M,
or use the variantingredients variable with commit=True. and images variable also on def formset_images_valid().
You'll need to replace the comments with the specific code for your models' relationships and signals.

I tried commit=True and I get the following error: ValueError at /recipe/create/
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'recipe'.
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/recipe/create/
Django Version: 5.0.7
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'recipe'.

I wrote the full code on my gist, check it and try to your code. Take it Here :
https://gist.github.com/soedarhanaINJ/dcd790074957eb78fd5b53d5ff9544ef

I believe this may have solved my issue- if you could post the solution as an answer I will accept it
